# Mark as Obsolete

Tags: c++, obsolete

I am trying to find all the unused methods of my project. I have search ways of doing this, but the most convincing answer I found was to declare all my functions as obsolete, and remove this attribute until I got no warnings.

The problem is that I don't know how to declare a function as obsolete. When I write:

```
   [Obsolete]
   class Vector3{

   };
```

VS2005 tells me that Obsolete does not exist.
Any suggestions?

Comment: do you mean unused as in "Not referenced in code" or unused as in "Not used during typical execution"

Comment: both. There may be unused code (not referenced in code) that references other methods (these are referenced, but never executed).

Comment: @jon hanson: it's C#. I guess the OP was looking for an equivalent in C++.

Comment: Ah, ok. @Sara: BTW, if you like Mark B's answer you should "Accept" it.

Answer (score 8):

In gcc you use `__attribute__ ((deprecated))` to tag functions as deprecated.

It looks like `__declspec(deprecated)` may do the trick in VS. You'll also have to enable warning level 1 for it to result in a diagnostic.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/044swk7y%28VS.80%29.aspx

Comment: Easiest way is to add a single `#if defined(_MSCVER) #define DEPRECATED __declspec(deprecated) #elif defined(__GNUC__) #define DEPRECATED __attribute__ ((deprecated)) #endif`, so you can then write `DEPRECATED class Vector3`.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the rest of your source code, but you should have a

```
using System;
```

at the top.

Comment: Try `[System.ObsoleteAttribute]` to see if that fixes it.

Comment: Now it says the System doesn't exist.

Comment: That's C#. The OP is using C++.

Comment: Ah sorry, overlooked the c++ tag.